# How to make a common /boot partition for multiple linux distros?

Tags: kernel, boot, grub2, initramfs, multiboot

I'm trying to multiboot windows along with two linux distros namely Parrot OS Electro Ara and Ubuntu 20.04 and grub and bootloader was initially installed by Parrot OS. So to not interfere that I installed Ubuntu without bootloader i.e. by `ubiquity -b` because I just want to use the grub of Parrot itself.

But I used the same **/boot** partition (`/dev/nvme0n1p9`) as mountpoint for both OS.
Here are my mount points from Parrot OS by `lsblk`

```
    NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1                                       259:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1                                   259:1    0   260M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─(windows partitions were hided)
├─nvme0n1p7                                   259:7    0   200M  0 part  
├─nvme0n1p8                                   259:8    0     4G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─nvme0n1p9                                   259:9    0     1G  0 part  /boot
├─nvme0n1p10                                  259:10   0    20G  0 part  /
├─nvme0n1p11                                  259:11   0    40G  0 part  /opt
├─nvme0n1p12                                  259:12   0    40G  0 part  
│ └─luks-...(UUID Hided)                      253:0    0    40G  0 crypt /home
└─nvme0n1p15                                  259:15   0  47.4G  0 part
```

Note: I had shared same `/opt` and `/boot` (efi partition is shared by default)

I'm getting a message like ubuntu was detected on the /dev/nvme0n1p15 but when I see the source code or boot from grub screen it points me directly to parrot OS.
The thing is parrot OS was booted by initramfs and vmlinuz file of ubuntu and it got booted into parrot without a problem. Similarly when I tried `update-grub` from ubuntu I says parrot OS but still it uses kernels (5.16 and 5.18) of Parrot OS to boot into ubuntu due to which I got errors due to initramfs but no error when I boot from its kernel 5.15.

Here is my grub-customizer page to show how it looks like. (The custom ones are I made them to boot temporarily into Ubuntu image).

[image]

Here I also attach the files that were present in the `/boot` folder before installing, after installing ubuntu and after running update-grub.

**Before installing Ubuntu (only Parrot and Windows)**

```
config-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
config-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
efi
grub
initrd.img-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
initrd.img-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
System.map-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
System.map-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
vmlinuz-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
vmlinuz-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
```

**After installing ubuntu and running update grub from it by chrooting**

```
total 256M
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K செப். 20 16:36 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4.0K செப். 20 16:36 grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   28 செப். 20 16:36 initrd.img -> initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 117M செப். 20 16:36 initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  94M செப். 20 16:36 initrd.img-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  14M செப். 20 16:36 initrd.img-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   32 செப். 20 16:36 initrd.img.old -> initrd.img-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 179K செப். 20 16:36 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 181K செப். 20 16:36 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 181K செப். 20 16:36 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 6.0M செப். 20 16:36 System.map-5.15.0-46-generic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   83 செப். 20 16:36 System.map-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   83 செப். 20 16:36 System.map-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   25 செப். 20 16:36 vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  11M செப். 20 16:36 vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.1M செப். 20 16:36 vmlinuz-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 7.2M செப். 20 16:36 vmlinuz-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
```

**Finally running update-grub from Parrot OS and removed symlinks**

```
config-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
config-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
efi
grub
initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
initrd.img-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
initrd.img-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
memtest86+.bin
memtest86+.elf
memtest86+_multiboot.bin
System.map-5.15.0-46-generic
System.map-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
System.map-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
vmlinuz-5.15.0-46-generic
vmlinuz-5.16.0-12parrot1-amd64
vmlinuz-5.18.0-1parrot1-amd64
```

The solution I'm wanting is to have grub boot options like

- Parrot
- Advance options for Parrot
- Ubuntu
- Advance options for Ubuntu
- Windows

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why so complicated? You don't need `/boot` if `/` is not crypted. Just use one partition for parrot's `/` and another partition for Ubuntu `/`.

Comment: Trying to share system partitions, even with similar distributions almost always leads to issues. Some setting in one interferes with setting in the other. You can share data, but not system folders/partitions.

Comment: @Erich when I install linux for the first time, some articles in the internet told to do so. Hence, I made a separate /boot partition.

Comment: @oldfred but I remembered that /boot can be created with 1GiB of space not usual 256 MiB or something, and It can be shared between distros. So only I'm asking for this method.